# Div is showing with delay of 2-3 seconds on a CMS after height change, Is there alternative

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change an element's height as soon as possible after page loads, as it's third party CMS on which my code is running so I am not sure what could be done, this is what i have tried so far,

```
var myWindow = myWindow || {};

myWindow.Resize = function () {
    //$(".container-box").height($("#contentRow").height() - 15);
    setHeight("container-box", $("#contentRow").height() - 15);
};

window.onload = function () {
    myWindow.Resize();
    //$("#container-root").show();
    showStuff("container-root");
    $(window).resize(myWindow.Resize());
}

function showStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}

function setHeight(className, size) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(className).height = size;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it seems to be slow`? The fastest possible should be vanilla, everything else is just a wraparound from vanilla. You could change the class of the element and let the CSS handle the height, but I don't know if this can make it any faster or better for your requierements xD

Comment: am i already trying the fastest code ?

Comment: *why* are you looking to change the height? Would percentage based units not be able to do this? However, It's hard to say without a use case.

Comment: You've shown what you tried, but what do you expect and what are you getting? How do you know this is slow? Besides caching the NodeList, I doubt it could be much faster.

Comment: you marked this with jQuery...then didn't use jQuery at all...

Comment: @abc123: `$(window).resize(...)` uses jQuery, as does part of `Resize`. It's pretty inconsistent, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to guess that by "slow" you mean it doesn't happen until the div has already been visible for a while.

The reason is that you're using the `load` event, which doesn't happen until **very** late in the page load cycle.

If you want to change the height as soon as possible, put your script tag at the bottom of the page and do it immediately, without waiting for `load`.

If you *can't* put your script tag at the bottom of the page (some CMS's are difficult), you can use jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) callback, which happens much sooner than `load`:

```
    $(myWindow.Resize);
```

---

Side note: Your `resize` handler hookup is incorrect:

```
$(window).resize(myWindow.Resize());
// Remove these ----------------^^
```

With the () there, you're **calling** `myWindow.Resize()` and passing its return value (`undefined`) into `$(window).resize(...)`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

---

Also note that your `setHeight` function just won't work at all. You're using `getElementsByClassName` and then assigning to a `height` property on what you get back. But what you get back is a collection of elements, not a single element, and that collection doesn't have a `height` property.

The commented-out jQuery line above where you call `setHeight` would work.

Comment: thanks, i'll do that